# Returning data from $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I have this function:

```
    function getNamep(id_user) {
    $.post('php/back.php', {
        id: id_user,
        f: "getName"
    }, function (data) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (data[0] == 1) {
            console.log(data)
        }
        else {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

I want to get the result here:

```
var name = getNamep(2);
```

How i can do this? Returning data from $.post()

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callback`.

```
function getName(id_user, cb) {
    $.post('php/back.php', {
        id: id_user,
        f: "getName"
    }, function (data) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (data[0] == 1) {
            console.log(data)
        }
        else {
            console.log(data)
        }
      if(cb) cb(data);
    });
}

function getResponse(name){
  console.log(name);
  htmlList = '<div class="desc">' + '<div class="thumb">' + '</div>' + 
             '<div class="details">' + "<p><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"messageCamp('" + v + "')\">" 
             + name + "</a><br/>" + '<muted>Available</muted>' + '</p>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
}
getName(1, getResponse);
```

Comment: I need to get the result here: >" + getName(7, getResponse) + "< i tried to use return, but not working, i still get undefined

Comment: It is not synschronous call, you will get value of name inside `getResponse` function.

Comment: Can you show the code how are you using?

Comment: htmlList = '<div class="desc">' +
                '<div class="thumb">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="details">' +
                "<p><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"messageCamp('" + v + "')\">" + getName(7, getResponse) + "</a><br/>" +
                '<muted>Available</muted>' +
                '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: I can't use the getName() in that way? Just to assign his value in another var, like var test = getName(1,getResponse);

Comment: That is not a synchronous call that will return some value. That is asynchronous call, you can' do that

Comment: Not working, but thanks for the attenttion !